# Issues removing page number from single page with large figure

Tags: graphics, floats

I have a full page figure that I would like to remove the bottom-center page number from. What I have tried is not working, any suggestions?

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
              \includegraphics[angle=90,width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{figure_abu}
\caption{\textbf{{Distribution Plot}}}
\label{fig: Abundance}
\end{figure}
```

My preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside, 11pt, openany]{memoir}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{palatino}
\setlength{\parindent}{2.5em}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp, backend=biber, ibidtracker=constrict]{biblatex}
\providecommand*{\mkibid}[1]{#1}
\newbibmacro*{cite:ibid}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{\bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidem}}}
\makeatother
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[inner=2.5cm,outer=2.5cm,  tmargin=2.5cm, bmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{color}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{-2pt}{\HUGE}
```

Comment: Any error messages?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. When I make your code snippet compilable by prefixing the instructions `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{afterpage,graphicx}\begin{document}` and affixing the instruction `\end{document}`, I get a *page without a page number*. Thus, I can't reproduce the problem you are encountering. (BTW, the instructions `\thispagestyle{empty}` and `\centering` *inside* the `figure` enviroment are not needed.) Please edit your posting to create an example that generates the problem behavior you're looking to fix. Please also indicate which TeX distribution and which TeX format you use.

Comment: I've added some more... its still not working for me

Comment: @user113636 - Unless you provide a fully compilable example that actually gerates the problem you say you're encountering, it's not going to be easy to provide a diagnosis of what's going on, let alone a cure. (Aside: Virtually all of the preamble instructions you've posted have almost certainly nothing to do with the problem at hand.)

Comment: What more do you need? I am not centering the figure or text around, thats why its unusual

Comment: A figure creates a savebox which is generally displayed elsewhere.  Most importantly, any global counters are incremented (or decremented) immediately.  What you can do is delay writing to the aux file to locate which page the figure is actually on, then use everypage to perform whatever needs to be done.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/307082/full-page-landscape-figure-in-middle-of-document/307142?noredirect=1#comment804 for example.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really want `afterpage` here, the `float` package allows you to specify different formatting on float pages so for example you could define the center of the footline to be

```
\iffloatpage{}{\thepage}
```

Comment: Where do I add this?